# ServiceProvider must have at least one public constructor to be plugged in by StructureMap

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, structuremap, service-provider

I am trying to use an internal plugin (organisation specific) for some task implementation, in order to call the methods through plugin I need to pass the dependencies.
I am done with the initial part but when I try to register in PreAppStart using:

```
config.For<IServiceProvider>().Use<ServiceProvider>()
```

I get below error:

```
    System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
  HResult=0x80131502
  Message=Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider must have at least one public constructor to be plugged in by StructureMap
```

My analysis:
I have got to know that the ServiceProvider class is used for dot net core but my solution is in standard dot net (4.7) and I need to implement this plugin in order to complete the work.

Also I have tried this:

```
   config.For<IServiceProvider>().Use<ServiceProvider>().Ctor<string>("randomParam").Is("ranVal");
```

but still the error is same. Please help!

Comment: What is your expectation what `config.For<IServiceProvider>().Use<ServiceProvider>()` does exactly? If you have a class that depends on `IServiceProvider`, how does it use that dependency and what expectations does it have (i.e. how should it be configured)?

Comment: Thanks for responding, it actually registers the dependency in the PreAppStart (which is used for registering all the dependencies) class of my solution. Yes I have a nuget package reference (available only for organisation and not for public) which has a class that depends on IServiceProvider. Please let me know if I am not clear in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

You are telling structure map that when something needs a `IServiceProvider` it should create a `ServiceProvider` object. And it tells you that it cannot since `ServiceProvider` does not have a public constructor.

You probably want to register an actual object to use. like this

```
 config.For<IServiceProvider>().UseInstance(myServiceProviderReference);
```

There is some methods to [create a service provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectioncontainerbuilderextensions.buildserviceprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), but this is part of .Net platform extensions. I'm unsure if this is available for .net framework projects.